# Unit testing non-static Play! controllers

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

What's the proper way to write a unit test for a non-static controller in Play! 2.3 (using Java)?

**Example Controller**

```
package controllers;

public class MyController extends Controller {

  /**
   * Non-static method.
   */
  public Result index() {
    return ok();
  }
}
```

**Entry in `conf/routes`**

```
GET /my-controller @controllers.MyController.index()
```

If `index()` was static I could just use the "reverse" controller in my test:

```
@Test
public void callingIndex_ShouldReturnOk() {
  Result result = callAction(
    controllers.routes.ref.MyController.index(),
    new FakeRequest(GET, "/")
  );

  assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
}
```

However, I can't to get to the "reverse" controller in my test, even though the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting) seems to indicate it should work for all controllers in the routes file. What am I missing?

Comment: I could wrong due to my limited knowledge of the play framework but this looks a lot like an integration test rather than a unit test. Why can't you test the `index` method in isolation without going through the play framework?

Comment: I agree, it's really more of an integration test. I called it a "unit test" for this question because I was just modifying [an example from Play's docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTest), and that's what they called it there.